# Cannot use SQLite as backend in Celery

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a simple project which is without any framework such as Django or Flask.

My config is such:

```
CELERY_BROKER_BACKEND = "sqlakombu.transport.Transport"
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "db+sqlite:///results.sqlite"
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "db+sqlite:///results.sqlite"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "db+sqlite:///results.sqlite"
```

I have installed packages:

```
SQLAlchemy==1.2.8
kombu==4.2.0
kombu-sqlalchemy==1.1.0
celery==4.1.1
```

When I attempt to start celery:

```
celery worker -A proj --loglevel=info
```

I got this error:

```
File "/home/cyildiz/Projects/env/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 582, in get_transport_cls
transport_cls = get_transport_cls(transport_cls)
File "/home/cyildiz/Projects/env/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/__init__.py", line 83, in get_transport_cls     _transport_cache[transport] = resolve_transport(transport)
File "/home/cyildiz/Projects/env/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/__init__.py", line 64, in resolve_transport
raise KeyError('No such transport: {0}'.format(transport))
KeyError: u'No such transport: db'
```

When I change the settings into this:

```
CELERY_BROKER_BACKEND = "sqlakombu.transport.Transport"
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "sqla+sqlite:///results.sqlite"
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "sqla+sqlite:///results.sqlite"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "sqla+sqlite:///results.sqlite"
```

The error is:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named sqla
```

So, where do I make the mistake?

Comment: Or how can I install sqlite package for Kombu? I couldn't handle to do this.

Comment: Using sqlalchemy as a broker was removed from Celery 4.0 (released 11/2016)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, CELERY_BROKER_URL made this error, I have deleted that line and made the settings as:

```
CELERY_BROKER_BACKEND = "db+sqlite:///celery.sqlite"
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "db+sqlite:///celery.sqlite"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "db+sqlite:///celery.sqlite"
```

Now it works.